# Como exibir subplots de escopos diferentes na mesma figura?

Tags: python, otimização, matplotlib, aprendizagem-de-máquina

**1 - Resumo do problema**

Estou tentando implementar o Problema da Mochila Binária, usando Python e um algoritmo genético simples.

Segue o [repositório](https://github.com/ZaqueuCavalcante/002-knapsack-problem) no GitHub.

Escrevi funções para plotagem do espaço de busca (um gráfico de espalhamento mostrando os indivíduos da geração atual) e da função objetivo (com as respectivas aptidões dos indivíduos).

Queria saber se é possível plotar os dois gráficos na mesma figura, como subplots, para acompanhar a execução do programa mais facilmente. Do jeito que está, a cada chamada de função, são gerados subplots diferentes, como segue:

[image: Saída gráfica do Spyder]

**2 - O que você já tentei**

Tentei utilizar `plt.subplot(121)` e `plt.subplot(122)` nas respectivas funções, mas são gerados subplots diferentes.

Tentei gerar os subplots direto no programa principal (main.py), logo antes de chamar as funções, sem sucesso.

Answer (score 0):

Use `subplot2grid()` documentacao aqui https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html